# Cannot reach Jolokia JVM agent

Tags: jolokia

I'm trying to connect my Jolokia JVM agent with an hawtio frontend.

The agent runs inside of a docker container with the [distroless java 11](http://gcr.io/distroless/java:11) image.

I start the application like this:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-javaagent:jolokia-agent.jar","-jar","service1.jar"]
```

The Jolokia version is 1.6.2.

When I start up the application, this appears first.

```
| I> No access restrictor found, access to any MBean is allowed
| Jolokia: Agent started with URL http://127.0.0.1:8778/jolokia/
```

In my docker-compose.override file, I forward the port:

```
services:
   service1:
     ports:
       - "8778:8778"
```

However, when I try to access the endpoint from the browser, it cannot reach it.
When I try curl `curl "http://localhost:8778/jolokia` from inside the container, I also cannot reach it.